# Scaling height and width of transformable node in AR-Core (Ar Fragment)

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform

I am currently using **AR-Core (Ar fragment)**, I have placed a transformable node to the ar fragment, and I can scale its x, y, and z coordinate with the pinch gesture. But the problem here is on changing the zooming in the transformable node, it scales with equal proportion. I want to scale x, y, z of transformable node separately with the help of pinch gesture.

For Example, If I perform the gesture in the x direction, then only the x-axis alone should scale, on changing the y-direction y-axis should change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you have a `TransformableNode` and by default a `ScaleController` scales your model. The [ScaleController](https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/blob/master/sceneformux/ux/src/main/java/com/google/ar/sceneform/ux/ScaleController.java) is listening on the `PinchGesture`. It's scaling the node in all direction because its logic is simplified and it computes only one scale variable which is applied for all directions:

https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/blob/master/sceneformux/ux/src/main/java/com/google/ar/sceneform/ux/ScaleController.java#L111

```
@Override
public void onContinueTransformation(PinchGesture gesture) {
    currentScaleRatio += gesture.gapDeltaInches() * sensitivity;

    float finalScaleValue = getFinalScale();
    Vector3 finalScale = new Vector3(finalScaleValue, finalScaleValue, finalScaleValue);
    getTransformableNode().setLocalScale(finalScale);

    if (currentScaleRatio < -ELASTIC_RATIO_LIMIT
        || currentScaleRatio > (1.0f + ELASTIC_RATIO_LIMIT)) {
        gesture.cancel();
    }
}
```

As you see the `finalScale = new Vector3(finalScaleValue, finalScaleValue, finalScaleValue);` line. I'd spin-off my own `ScaleController` (by inheriting from that built-in `ScaleController`) which manages `x`, `y`, `z` pinches in separate variables. You'd need to override that `onContinueTransformation` function and having a `Vector3 currentScaleVector` and `Vector3 finalScaleVector` instead of `float` ones. Then when you instantiate your [TransformableNode](https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/blob/master/sceneformux/ux/src/main/java/com/google/ar/sceneform/ux/TransformableNode.java) you can specify a [TransformationSystem](https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/blob/master/sceneformux/ux/src/main/java/com/google/ar/sceneform/ux/TransformableNode.java#L35), and the `ScaleController` is one part of that `TransformationSystem`, so you'd pass in your overridden ScaleController to the system.

```
scaleController = new ScaleController(this, transformationSystem.getPinchRecognizer());
addTransformationController(scaleController);
```

What I don't see clearly right now on the [PinchGesture](https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/blob/master/sceneformux/ux/src/main/java/com/google/ar/sceneform/ux/PinchGesture.java) interface how you'd obtain the `Vector3` gap, and not just the float one. If push comes to shove private fields (`startPosition1`, `previousPosition1`) can be read but that would be a hack.

Comment: Now,  I can able to change height and width separately with the help of a custom scale controller with pinch gesture. In order to change the height I'm considering x from vector 3 of start position (pinch gesture), and for width, y from vector 3. But when I try to change length that is z from vector 3, the value which I get for z from vector 3 of start position from the pinch gesture is always zero. So how can I achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @AbdulWajid can you please guide me through the same I am  having hard time to achieve same.